# Apache runs several processes slows server, MYSQL can't connect, always fixed after reboot

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache2, mpm-prefork

My WordPress Web Server will run for 30 - 60 minutes (then go down, and run very slowly as a server, difficult to input using Putty, or KVM terminal), after a reboot it will run fine, then Apache will run several processes ([screenshot](https://snipboard.io/udj4pZ.jpg):) and go down again.

The WordPress debug.log will fill with errors ([screenshot](https://snipboard.io/R0x8ZP.jpg):).

I have been able to resolve a few of the errors:

`[29-Dec-2019 20:27:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divi/Divi/functions.php on line 73`

I added `'`  (missing single quotes) to `'REQUEST_URI'` on `line 71`, which seems to have fixed things.

I've also done the following:

Limited the Apache Processes in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.  I used this guide: 
[Tuning an Apache Server in 5 Minutes](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tuning-an-apache-server-in-5-minutes)

`<IfModule prefork.c>`
`StartServers       4`
`MinSpareServers    3`
`MaxSpareServers   10`
`ServerLimit      256`
`MaxClients       256`
`MaxRequestsPerChild  10000`
`</IfModule>`

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

256 Clients in Apache is causing the trouble; shrink that to 30.

Swapping is terrible for performance, especially for MySQL.

As the screenshot says, do *not* use the `mysql_*` interface.  Also, do not mix the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` calls.

Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size to only 700M`.

If you still have trouble after those changes, come back for more advice.